# Leaflet for R: dealing with missing values

Tags: r, leaflet, na

I'm new to Leaflet and am wondering how it deals with missing values. Suppose I have a data frame with many columns, holding coordinates and other attributes. Ideally, if the `addCircleMarkers` function comes upon a missing latitude or longitude value, it would skip it and not plot that row's coordinates. However, what I've been encountering it that if there's a single missing latitude/longitude value, no points at all will be drawn.

I can imagine going row by row in my data and checking for any NAs, and only plotting if there are none. But I feel like Leaflet would have a built-in way to deal with this. Does anyone know?

edit: Since somebody asked, here's my code for adding the markers (using the magrittr `%>%` operator):

```
addCircleMarkers(~lon, ~lat, stroke=F,
      fillOpacity = .6, color = coloring(), radius=radii) %>%
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you are using addCircleMarkers? My knee-jerk reaction would be to say just provide a subset of your data using subset() and remove the rows with NAs, but I'm not sure that applies to how you are using the Leaflet functions.

Comment: I understand the question, but you could quickly do it with  `df[complete.cases(df), ]`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That works great, except if I have other rows that have NA values. Is there a way to remove just the rows with missing latitude/longitude, using `complete.cases`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like, to test both lat and long columns

```
(df <- data.frame(a = c(1, NA, 4, NA), b = c(1, 2, 3, 5)))

   a b
1  1 1
2 NA 2
3  4 3
4 NA 5

bools <- apply(cbind(complete.cases(df$a), complete.cases(df$b)), 1, all)
df[bools, ]

  a b
1 1 1
3 4 3
```

Comment: That's great! I did that and then saved the result back into `df` and used that throughout the mapping (when I make the initial map and all subsequent `leafletProxy`). Thanks!

Comment: great. FYI they know about this issue and perhaps a fix soon https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/71  Leaflet.js doesn't like missing data, but they can remove them on the R side